# Filter by financial period Sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, case

I'm trying to bring though all data through from the current financial year.
Please see my code below.

```
       select *

   FROM            dbo.vw_AN_Admin_VendorReturns

       where 
           case  month(getdate()) <4  -- If current month is less than April (old financial year)
               year(RtnDt) = year(getdate()) and month(RtnDt) <4 or year(RtnDt) = year(getdate())-1 and month(RtnDt) >3 

            case  month(getdate()) >3 -- If current month is more than March (New financial year)
                year(RtnDt) = year(getdate()) and month(RtnDt) >3 or year(RtnDt) = year(getdate())+1 and month(RtnDt) <4
            end
```

Comment: unable to understand ur que..

Comment: Explain what are you trying to do???

Comment: Please post the sample data and expected result/

Comment: @Praveen how is it that I post data?

Comment: @Krishn Include data in the question or provide sqlfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Krishn, Depending on your brief description, this should solve your problem.

```
select * 
from dbo.vw_AN_Admin_VendorReturns
Where 
Case 
    When Month(getdate())<4 
        Then Year(getdate())-1 
    Else 
        Year(getdate()) 
End 
= 
Case 
    When Month(RtnDt)<4 
        Then Year(RtnDt)-1 
    Else Year(RtnDt) 
End
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you may be searching for these formulas.

```
declare @toDate datetime = dateadd(day, -day(GETDATE()), GETDATE())
declare @fromDate datetime = dateadd(year, -1, @toDate)
```

Just decreasing the current date by the number of days gives you the last day of preceding month and decrease that date by one year to get the 1 year period.

```
select 
  D.* 
from mydata D
where D.RtnDt > @fromDate and D.RtnDt <= @toDate
```

You don't have to declare the variables, just for a better reading.
Hope this helps.